# Always ON Connection string issue

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

In the environment I am currently working, the connection string which is being used is wrong **( AG_LISTENER_Name\InstanceName).** This is something we need to correct in all apps that is configured. Today we ran into an issue where the Listener_Name connects to Other instances from other boxes when the port number is not specified. The AG name resolves fine but then connects to some random instance when used without port. We want to use only the AG-Name to connect to particular instances. My questions :

1. Can we use 1433 as the listener port for all the instances in a box? ( read it can be done)
2. If yes, then will there be anything else that needs to be done? ( To avoid port conflict if any)
3. How to explain the scenario where the Listener (without port) connects to random instance.

Comment: Have you already reviewed [SQL CAT's article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2014/02/03/alwayson-availability-groups-listener-named-instances-port-numbers-etc/) about listener configuration options?

Comment: @vonPryz Checking it now. Thanks for the link.